# SQL Join : Multiple join with multiple values

Tags: sql

I have following 2 Table Customer, Parameters

Customer Table

| ID | Name | City | State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Kapil | C1 | S1 |
| 123 | Ram | C2 | S2 |
| 123 | Shyam | C3 | S1 |

Parameter Table

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| C1 | Mumbai |
| C2 | Jaipur |
| C3 | Nagpur |
| S1 | Mah |
| S2 | Raj |

I want to write a select query in which out put should be as beloow

Customer.ID | Customer.Name | Parameter.Name (for City} | Parameter.Name (State)

Is there any way to achive the same in single query

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select Customer.ID, Customer.Name, p1.Name as city,  p2.Name as state
from Customer
left join Parameter as p1 on p1.ID = Customer.city
left join Parameter as p2 on p2.ID = Customer.state
```

Comment: Please do not mix lower- and uppercase in you aliases, see: [Why are table aliases commonly lowercase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229066/why-are-table-aliases-commonly-lowercase)